# ReactNative Firestore multiple wheres and comparing result

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a function in my app that allows the user to choose two medicaments and in a third screen get the result whether these two have interactions.

For this I have a database with the interactions the chosen medicamentations pass an "ATC" number, called GRP1D or GRP2D in the interaction database. The two ATC numbers passed should be compared with the GRPD numbers in the database in order to return the interaction, or if there is none, "No interaction" should be returned. Idealy I would use multiple where clauses combined with an OR clause to make the sequence of the passed ATC numbers irrelevant.

I have tried a lot of things but in the end I am not even sure this is possible with firestore. Here is the relevant part of the database [image]

Below is the code that I would like for it to work, obviously it doesn't because there doesn't seem to be an OR or even multiple where clauses in firestore. Any Idea how this could be solved? Thanks a lot in advance!

```
render() {
   console.log(this.state.atc1);
    console.log(this.state.atc2);
    var atc1 = this.state.atc1
    var atc2 = this.state.atc2
    var interactiondescription
    dbh.collection('IX')
      .where('GRP1D', '==', atc1)
      .where('GRP2D', '==', atc2)
      or
      .where('GRP1D', '==', atc2)
      .where('GRP2D', '==', atc1)
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {

         interactiondescription = doc.data().MEASD
        console.log('this', interactiondesctription)
        })
      });

    //console.log('Desc:', this.interactiondescription)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've already found, Cloud Firestore doesn't support OR type conditions. That means that you'll need to run a separate query for each of these ORs, which luckily isn't too bad in your case:

```
let query1 = dbh.collection('IX')
  .where('GRP1D', '==', atc1)
  .where('GRP2D', '==', atc2);
let query2 = dbh.collection('IX')
  .where('GRP1D', '==', atc2)
  .where('GRP2D', '==', atc1);
Promise.all([query1.get(), query2.get()])
  .then((querySnapshots) => {
    console.log('Queries executed: ', querySnapshots);
    let querySnapshot = !querySnapshots[0].empty() ? querySnapshots[0] : querySnapshots[1];
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      interactiondescription = doc.data().MEASD
      console.log(interactiondesctription)
    })
  });
```

This executes two queries and when both are done, it takes the one that has results and loops over that.

---

If the ordering of your `GRP1D` and `GRP2D` doesn't matter, you could also consider having an single array field `GRPDs` in your documents with both/all `GRPD` values:

```
GRPDs: ["atc2", "atc1"]
```

With such a field you could use a single [`array-contains-any` query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any) to get the documents for up to 10 values:

```
dbh.collection('IX').where('GRPDs', 'array-contains-any', [atc1, atc2]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

How do I get the Documents Fields GRPD1 and GRPD2 from the Database in to an Array? also in the query you wrote GRPDs , which isn't a Document Field in the Firebase

Comment: As said: "you could also consider having an single array field `GRPDs` in your documents with both/all GRPD values". So this would be a new field to allow for this query.

Comment: This would be a field in the database, right? I am not sure how to get that done.

Also, the first solution doesnt seem to return anything for some reason. interactiondescription stays "undefined" and the console.log in the querysnapshot doesnt return anything at all...

I am new to this, sorry if I am asking obvious things.

Comment: I populated the db with a large json file with a script.

Comment: In that case, you can still use the approach in the first part of my answer using two queries.

Comment: For some reason, that doesn't return anything. It doesn't go in to the querysnapshot and the console.log in there doesn't return anything at all.

Comment: I added an extra log statement to help troubleshoot. Can you try that and tell me the output. It would also help if you can reproduce the problem on a site like jsbin or stackblitz, so that we can both look at the same reproduction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The log statement you added doesn't show up at all when executing the code. I will try to get on stackblitz but not sure they support react-native.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215116/discussion-between-landyandolt-and-frank-van-puffelen).

Comment: It's also fine if you find a similar online environment that can run react-native code. But it might be simpler to reproduce it with regular ReactJS, or (even better) with just plain JavaScript code. They all work the same on the level of the code that you shared. The fewer/less advanced the dependencies, the more likely it is we can spot the problem.

Comment: I didnt really figure it out... Did you mean to restructure the whole database or add the two values to an array in the code getting the data from the database. How would that even work?